# How to remove url from text message and send that url to separate url list in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

can someone help me as I have a textbox and a button. TextBox will contain message including URL like (Hiya see www.xyz.com and let me know) and when the user click the button that url will remove from the actual message but send to the separate column called "URL list" in datagrid.

I have done URL removing stuff but struggling to send those URL to URL column in datagrid. I was thinking to create another text box and send only URL string from first text box to second text box but it's still removing as second text box is clone of first one. Any suggestion? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what other data you may have in your DataGridView control, but one way to do this would be to bind it to a private `BindingList<string>` that contains the Urls you want to display. Then, after you parse the Url out of the string, you can just add it to the `BindingList`.

For example:

```
// This will hold the urls
private ObservableCollection<string> urls = new ObservableCollection<string>();

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Parse the url from our text and add it to our collection
    urls.Add(GetUrlFromText(textBox.Text));
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = urls.Select(s => new { Urls = s });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I ask where I have to add
private ObservableCollection<string> urls = new ObservableCollection<string>(); on textchanged event?

Comment: You can add it where I did, can't you?